# Protocol Buffer method definition. Pass in arguments

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to define a method in java using protocol buffers where the return type is a boolean but the method argument is a set of enums. this is the desired method

**public boolean isXyz(Set enums)**

How do i define the message in .proto file to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, "define a method in Java using protocol buffers"?  Is the method just supposed to accept an protocol buffer type as an argument?

Comment: no I want to define a member in protocol buffer that yields the above method! im not able to find how to pass in a method argument that is different from the return type!

Comment: The only support protocol buffers have for adding methods with custom signatures is in RPC services, which I don't think is really what you want?  Protocol buffer types are dumb data types, and don't really support adding extra functionality in any way other than wrapping them in your own Java type.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i realized that! I might have to handle it in different way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only support protocol buffers have for adding methods with custom signatures is in RPC services, which I don't think is really what you want? Protocol buffer types are dumb data types, and don't really support adding extra functionality in any way other than wrapping them in your own Java type